# Layer does not show in both versions of QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-7.6

I was originally using QGIS 3 and i recently download QGIS Desktop 3.8.2 with Grass 7.6.1. All of the layers can be seen in both except a layer called Masspoint. This layer is not showing up in QGIS Desktop 3.8.2 with Grass. when I check the properties, it shows the feature count but does not show the points. Why does this show up in QGIS3 but not in QGIS Desktop with Grass? All other layers are visible.

Comment: Please provide as much information as you can about the problematic layer. What file format, what geometry type, how is it styled, etc.